# task that runs R script source code located in startTask folder

Tags: python, rscript, azure-batch

**During the startTask:**

1) I downloaded to each node a R script called test.R to a folder call source_code. The file test.R is located here:

```
'%AZ_BATCH_NODE_STARTUP_DIR%\\wd\\source_code'
```

2) I downloaded an image called img001.jpg to be processed by the test.R script. This image is located here:

```
'%AZ_BATCH_NODE_STARTUP_DIR%\\wd\\image'
```

**Then:**

I created a job (called job_001) and a task(called task_001). The task is supposed to run a command_line:

```
cmd /c "RScript.exe %AZ_BATCH_NODE_STARTUP_DIR%\\wd\\source_code\\test.R %AZ_BATCH_NODE_STARTUP_DIR%\\wd\\image\\img001.jpg
```

The task failed!

**My question**:

Could you please confirm that I can have a task that runs RScript.exe from the working directory (i.e. root/workitems/Job_001/job-1/task_001/wd) which use two files (i.e. test.R and img001.jpg) respectively located into folders (root/workitems/Job_001/job-1/task_001/wd *and* root/startup/wd/source_code)

**My idea**

My idea was to copy during the startTask everything I need (sourcecode, image, etc..) to be run on a node.

Hence, I would like to create tasks that can call those files located on disk node (i.e. in a given folder in the startup folder).

Copy the output of each task into shared folder on the node to finally copy that back to blob storage using Job Release Task.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: You're missing a trailing quote in your command line, but if that was a typo you will need to provide more details other than "The task failed!" - what was the stderr/stdout, etc? Have you checked via [Batch Explorer](https://azure.github.io/BatchExplorer/) if the files in the startup directory exist that you're referencing from the task? Additionally, you should use [job preparation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/batch/batch-job-prep-release) facilities instead of copying things during node start task to "prep" jobs.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @fpark, yes there is a typo and I double check that works fine now. It will provide more details next time (i.e. stderr/stdout) I post a question.
Great input about job preparation, I am going to use it.